# how do I calculate the amount of years to reach the required balance without getting an infinite loop?

Tags: java, do-while

I am currently doing software fundamentals tutorials for university and I am currently stuck on this problem.

"Calculate the number of years it will take to get a specified amount of money in a bank
account, assuming that interest is paid at the end of each year, and no withdrawals are
made.
The program should prompt the user to input the current balance in pounds, the required
balance in pounds and the rate of interest as a percentage. It should then calculate and
output the number of years it will take to achieve the required balance, outputting the
current balance at the end of each year."

I have tried this so far and I have also tried moving the variables around but it always does an infinite loop.
How do I stop this?

```
package interest;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Interest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("hello what is your current balance ?");
        double balance = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is your required Balance");
        Double requiredBal = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("what is your current interest rate in %");
        double interest = input.nextDouble();
        int years = 0;
        double totalbalance=0;

        do {

            double intbalance = (balance /100) * interest;
            totalbalance = balance + intbalance;
            years ++;
            System.out.println("your balance after " + years +" years = " + totalbalance);

        }while(totalbalance <= requiredBal);
        System.out.println("it will take" + years + " years to get to " + requiredBal);
    }

}
```

it should so something like this

```
enter current balance
100
enter required balance
200
enter interest rate   
10
balance after 1 year = 110.0 
balance after 2 year = 120.0  
balance after 3 year = 130.0 
balance after 4 year = 140.0
balance after 5 year = 150.0 
balance after 6 year = 160.0 
balance after 7 year = 170.0
balance after 8 year = 180.0
balance after 9 year = 190.0 
balance after 10 year = 200.0
It will take 10 years to reach the required balance.
```

Comment: You don't need `totalbalance`, just replace it with `balance` and it should work fine. The problem is that you are recalculating total balance with the same value every time without any increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is these two lines:

```
    double intbalance = (balance /100) * interest;
    totalbalance = balance + intbalance;
```

`intbalance` and `totalbalance` are assigned the same value in every iteration of your loop. Hence your loop does not terminate.

I'm assuming you want compound interest, so try something like:

```
double totalbalance = balance;
do {
    double intbalance = (totalbalance / 100) * interest;
    totalbalance += intbalance;
    years++;
    System.out.println("your balance after " + years +" years = " + totalbalance);
} while(totalbalance <= requiredBal);
System.out.println("it will take" + years + " years to get to " + requiredBal);
```

You should also check that the initial balance and the required balance have sensible values.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do some baby math.

Exponential Growth is defined as `y=a(1+r)^x` where `a` is your initial value and `r` is your interest (between 0 and 1). This function maps bank account balance over X years. We want the inverse.

If you take the inverse of this equation you get `y=logx/(log[a(1+r)]`. 
This will tell you how many years until you reach a balance of `x` no need for loops if you can do a little bit of math.

Comment: I'm sorry this is just a software fundamentals class that is specifically asking for a while loop.